# Direct2D Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, direct2d

I am using Direct2D to develop my app's UI, both the desktop and Window Store versions, but I just became a little concerned when I couldn't find concrete information about Windows Store Apps supporting Direct2D.

I looked under the APIs for Desktop Apps and it shows Direct2D, however I can't find it under Window Store Apps APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Direct2D APIs are available for use in Windows Store Apps.

From your question, it's not clear which specific APIs are of interest, but MSDN has a [quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) showing how to draw to a [`Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.aspx) via Direct2D.